# How to find the differences between two queries identical in structure that have been read into DataTables? Return the changed values

Tags: c#, .net, xml, datatable, compare

What I am looking to do is query a database and then do a comparison against a past query from the same database table that has been saved into XML. I thought that I would be able to do this with DataTables, but it looks like they will not have this functionality.

I attempted to read the XML file into a DataSet then use this method.

```
    public DataTable compareSets(DataTable today, DataTable yesterday)
    {
        today.Merge(yesterday);

        DataTable d3 = yesterday.GetChanges();

        return d3;

    }
```

But this just returned everything. What I am looking for is to get values that were changed from one day to the next inside the database table.

Comment: You have declared the primary key?

Comment: You'd probably be better served by adding some sort of DateUpdated timestamp column to the table... Then in SQL Server syntax you could do: SELECT * FROM table WHERE DateUpdated > GETUTCDATE() - 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by declaring the primary key. This allowed the comparison to return the values that had changed. I also ended up having to write both files to XML before the comparison as it was giving an type mismatch error.

```
    public DataTable compareConfigs(DataTable today, DataTable yesterday)
    {
        DataTable dtCurrent = today;

        DataTable dtLast = yesterday;
        dtLast.AcceptChanges();

        DataTable dtChanges = null;

        dtLast.Merge(dtCurrent, true);

        dtChanges = dtLast.GetChanges(DataRowState.Unchanged);
        return dtChanges;

    }


static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Declaring the DataSets
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        DataSet dataSet2 = new DataSet();


        // reading in an XML file to DataTable
        dataSet.ReadXml(@"Path to saved XML query");
        DataTable yesterday = dataSet.Tables[0];
        yesterday.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { yesterday.Columns["Key"]};

        // reading in an xml file to datatable
        dataSet2.ReadXml(@"Path to saved XML query");
        DataTable today = dataSet2.Tables[0];
        today1.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { today1.Columns["Key"]};

        ConfigCompare comp = new ConfigCompare();
        DataTable mismatch = comp.compareConfigs(today, yesterday);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
get values that were changed
```

The key(s) of the rows that have changed? And also the columns that are different for each row?

What you're after needs further definition. You could also pull this off without leaving the database if you save the outcome of your query into a table. Then you could "select rowkey from june join july on june.whoID = july.whoID where june.importantColumn <> july.importantColumn" superfast.